# UART1 in NRF52840 board with VSCode (nrf connect sdk)

Tags: uart, firmware, nrf52840

everyone~
I'm using NRF52840 board for getting location data(latitude, longitude, satellites) from RYS8330.
Currently uart0 is used to another function. So I should use uart1 with another pins.
How can I initialize the uart1 and assign pins?

I had searched many samples in zephyr library. But I can't find anything similar to my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [DevAcademy](https://academy.nordicsemi.com/courses/nrf-connect-sdk-fundamentals/) guide on the nRF Connect SDK. In short, you can use [pinctrl](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/config_and_build/pin_control.html#pin-control) to change pins for the drivers.

EDIT: Since I should explain how instead of linking.
Docs are in the above [pinctrl link](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/config_and_build/pin_control.html#pin-control). For an example on pinctrl, see https://github.com/nrfconnect/sdk-nrf/blob/v2.5.0/samples/zigbee/ncp/boards/nrf52833dk_nrf52833.overlay, which is like this:

```
*
 * Copyright (c) 2021-2023 Nordic Semiconductor ASA
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-Nordic-5-Clause
 */

&uart1 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-0 = <&uart1_default_alt>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&uart1_sleep_alt>;
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
};

&uart0 {
    pinctrl-0 = <&uart0_default_alt>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&uart0_sleep_alt>;
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
};

&zephyr_udc0 {
    cdc_acm_uart0: cdc_acm_uart0 {
        compatible = "zephyr,cdc-acm-uart";
    };
};

&pinctrl {
    uart1_default_alt: uart1_default_alt {
        group1 {
            psels = <NRF_PSEL(UART_TX, 0, 6)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_RX, 0, 8)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_RTS, 0, 5)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_CTS, 0, 7)>;
        };
    };

    uart1_sleep_alt: uart1_sleep_alt {
        group1 {
            psels = <NRF_PSEL(UART_TX, 0, 6)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_RX, 0, 8)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_RTS, 0, 5)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_CTS, 0, 7)>;
            low-power-enable;
        };
    };

    uart0_default_alt: uart0_default_alt {
        group1 {
            psels = <NRF_PSEL(UART_RX, 1, 1)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_TX, 1, 2)>;
        };
    };

    uart0_sleep_alt: uart0_sleep_alt {
        group1 {
            psels = <NRF_PSEL(UART_RX, 1, 1)>,
                <NRF_PSEL(UART_TX, 1, 2)>;
            low-power-enable;
        };
    };

};

/ {
    chosen {
        ncs,zigbee-uart = &uart1;
    };
};
```

Comment: any affiliation with DevAcademy? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Thank you for your kindly comment. I did it as well as you tech me. Thank you.

Comment: Right starball, I was not aware that is how Stack Overflow works. I will edit my comment to add a direct explanation, and remember to not just link in the future. 
Thanks!

Comment: The DevAcademy guide is a Nordic Semiconductor guide on how to work with their products, such as the nRF52840, which this question is about. It is also free. Because of this, I would concider linking to the guide very similar to linking to documentation for the software which is asked about in this question